# Required parameter in Rails controller is false and throws error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

In one of my controllers I have the following line:

```
params.require(:advertiser).permit(:price)
```

If I try to submit a form for this controller through my front-end and without an advertiser param, `param` looks like this:

```
{"advertiser"=>false, "controller"=>"advertisers", "action"=>"create"}
```

With advertiser being false, I get an error:

```
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `permit' for false:FalseClass
```

What do I have to do to have an error shown on my front-end instead of throwing an exception?

Answer (score 0):

In order to call `permit` after `require(:advertiser)`, the value returned by `require(:advertiser)` must be a Hash. Here you have a `false` value, which means you are calling

```
false.permit(:price)
```

but `permit` is not defined on the `FalseClass`, it's defined on a `Hash`.

[`require` implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9ab2d030209d9608a6c866d83210f5b3b7d2319e/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L246-L253) checks for the existence of the value. However, `false` is considered a valid value, hence it is returned and the method doesn't raise.

If `params[:advertiser]` is supposed to hold a Hash, then it's strange it contains `false`. If no object is given, it should contain `nil`, not `false`. You probably have some bad configuration in the view.

The correct approach is to fix the view. However, if for whatever reason `false` is a correct value here, then you must check whether the value is false before calling `permit`.